# Save function to database errors on 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

My C# Application uses list boxes to connect tables of databases and update, delete, and create them. But when I want to change a relationship. It errors. I feel like it has something to do with the 'a' and 'w' property used in the `foreach` loops. Since they give this error when using the debug tool: `a.id=error CS0103:`

> The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

. It would be nice if you would keep the answer simple since I am not very experienced with C#.

I am using windows 10 with Microsoft SQL management studio.

```
public void Save(Company company)
{
    using (WebsiteDBEntities1 db = new WebsiteDBEntities1())
    {
            var dbCompany = db.Companies.Include("Developers").Include("Websites").SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == company.id) ?? new Company();

            dbCompany.name = company.name;
            dbCompany.location = company.location;
            dbCompany.revenue = company.revenue;
            dbCompany.founded_in = company.founded_in;

            //Developers
            dbCompany.Developers.Clear();
            foreach (Developer developer in company.Developers)
            {
                dbCompany.Developers.Add(db.Developers.Single(a => a.id == developer.id));
            }

            //Websites
            dbCompany.Websites.Clear();
            foreach (Website website in company.Websites)
            {
                dbCompany.Websites.Add(db.Websites.Single(w => w.id == website.id));
            }

            db.Companies.AddOrUpdate(dbCompany);
            db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: "The name 'a' does not exist in the current context" and "DbUpdateException" are two *very* different things.  The latter can't even happen if the former is happening, because the former would prevent the code from compiling.  Which is the actual error you're trying to resolve?  If you're trying to resolve the DbUpdateException, what is the error message with the exception?  As well as any inner exceptions?

Comment: What does `Developers` and `Websites` look like? That error specifical means that an attempt was made to use a name that does not exist in the class, namespace, or scope. Please [*see*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103) there for more information.

Comment: error CS0103 is compilation error you cant build your code without resolving  and please updtae your question  and try using system.linq namespace . i guess namespace is missing

Comment: are you able to build your solution?

Comment: As said: add `using System.Linq;` to the usings in your cs file.

Comment: The main error is DbUpdateException, not sure what causes this. Error: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.'. Also System.Linq is included.

Comment: In this case it's a one-to-many relationship, maybe this causes it because i do not save the relationship?